# Is there a way to change the style of an input field value with Javascript (onclick)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to figure out how to make a todo list. I have a list of input fields, each with a circle next to it. I want that, if you click on the circle, whatever you have typed in the input field so far has a line through it (textDecoration = "line-through"). But whenever I try to do this I get this error message:
"Uncaught TypeError: cannot set properties of undefined"

This is the code:

```
var task = document.getElementById("task");
  if (newcount % 2 === 0) {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    var newval = task.value;
    newval.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  } else {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
```

Comment: The "value" property of an `<input>` element is a string, and strings do not have "style" objects. You cannot style text inside of a text input.

Comment: So there is no way to strikethrough text in an input box?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I styled the input box rather than the value of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just style the input container, but for more, you can use `caret-color`